# How to load a .rtf file in RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I have two forms. If I click the button on the first form, I want it to automatically load the second form with the `RichTextBox` loaded with the `.rtf` file.

I want to ask for help in loading a `.rtf` file in the `RichTextBox` without the path being coded in the form? I tried using the `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`, but I'm having a hard time because I'm not that experienced programmer.

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
public void LoadMyFile()
{
   // Create an OpenFileDialog to request a file to open.
   OpenFileDialog openFile1 = new OpenFileDialog();

   // Initialize the OpenFileDialog to look for RTF files.
   openFile1.DefaultExt = "*.rtf";
   openFile1.Filter = "RTF Files|*.rtf";

   // Determine whether the user selected a file from the OpenFileDialog. 
   if(openFile1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK &&
      openFile1.FileName.Length > 0) 
   {
      // Load the contents of the file into the RichTextBox.
      richTextBox1.LoadFile(openFile1.FileName);
   }
}
```

Comment: I want to clarify my problem. The .rtf file is inside the project folder. I want the program to load it automatically without loading any dialog box. Thank you.

Comment: When you call Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() it returns the big/debug folder path. To be sure, print it and see what does it return. try string path="\\..\\..\\"+Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+filepath;

Comment: This is what I did, and it worked. Thank you.                 string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
string Chosen_File = "";
openFileDialog1.FileName = "Document.rtf";
Chosen_File = openFileDialog1.FileName;
richTextBox1.LoadFile(Chosen_File, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);